# Context.Activity.Attachment.Name is null

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm using MS Teams to upload a file (This_Is_MyFile14+ Final.xlsx) but I got an ArgumentNullException because the file.Name in below code is null. Interestingly, when i omit the "+" in my filename (This_Is_MyFile14 Final.xlsx), it works perfectly fine.

I also tried to upload it into an emulator, both filename works fine.

Is there something wrong with my code or is this something how MS Teams handle file names.

```
        var activity = stepContext.Context.Activity;
        if (activity.Attachments != null && activity.Attachments.Any())
        {
            var file = activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault();
            var fileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), file.Name);
            
            ...
            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have tried the following code and its working.
File name This_Is_MyFile14+ Final.xlsx is also uploaded in Teams

```
string filePath = Path.Combine("Files", context["filename"].ToString());
                    long fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
                    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
                    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
                    {
                        var fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
                        fileContent.Headers.ContentLength = fileSize;
                        fileContent.Headers.ContentRange = new ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, fileSize - 1, fileSize);
                        await client.PutAsync(fileConsentCardResponse.UploadInfo.UploadUrl, fileContent, cancellationToken);
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My file name is actually 52 char excluding the extension, do you think Teams has file name limit?

Comment: @MrCorn - We have tried with 60 char for file name. Still its working at our end. Could you please try with above code.